# CEP generate Measurement/Event not in UTC time but in Local

Tags: iot, complex-event-processing, esper, cumulocity

All Measurements came with a time-stamp (event time) of when the measurement was created. Some of these measurements are artificial ones, meaning that they are not created by the device itself, but by a CEP rule running inside the CoT.

```
The "normal" measurements have the time format coded as UTC 
[{ 
"id": "12704547", 
"data": { 
"data": { 
"time": "2016-07-25T15:24:11.000Z", 
"id": "1152930", 
"self": "http://testTenant.c8y.com/measurement/measurements/1152930", 
"source": { 
"id": "222812", 
"self": "http://testTenant.c8y.com/inventory/managedObjects/222812" 
}, 
"type": "tsystems_cumulocity_energymeter_digital_ping", 
"Energieverbrauch": { 
"Ping": { 
"unit": "Wh", 
"value": 1 
} 
} 
}, 
"realtimeAction": "CREATE" 
}, 
"channel": "/measurements/222812" 
}, { 
"successful": true, 
"channel": "/meta/connect" 
}]
```

But the "artificial" measurements (created by the CEP rule) use a timestamp with local time

```
[{ 
"id": "12704578", 
"data": { 
"data": { 
"time": "2016-07-25T17:24:00.952+02:00", 
"id": "1152931", 
"self": "http://testTenant.c8y.com/measurement/measurements/1152931", 
"source": { 
"id": "222812", 
"self": "http://testTenant.c8y.com/inventory/managedObjects/222812" 
}, 
"type": "tsystems_cumulocity_energymeter_power_consumption", 
"Leistung": { 
"Aggregation_1min": { 
"unit": "W", 
"value": 900 
} 
} 
}, 
"realtimeAction": "CREATE" 
}, 
"channel": "/measurements/222812" 
}]
```

The measurements from one device should always be encoded with the same timezone (UTC preferred) as different timezone can create problems in clients using that data.

I create the 'time' in the CEP with

```
current_timestamp().toDate() as time
```

Answer (score 1):

please use:

```
com.cumulocity.model.util.DateTimeUtils.newUTC(current_timestamp().toDate()) as dateTime,
```

instead of

```
current_timestamp().toDate() as time
```

in your cep rule.

Best regards,
Arkadiusz
Cumulocity Support Team